# Calculations for measuring a two-qubit system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Suppose I have the state $|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle - |10\rangle)$ that I want to measure in an arbitrary basis $$|A\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle \text{ and } |B\rangle = \beta^*|0\rangle  - \alpha^*|1\rangle$$

From my understanding, if I measure $|\psi\rangle$, the probability of seeing $|A\rangle$ is $$\langle A | \psi\rangle^2$$ But when I try to compute $\langle A | \psi\rangle$, I get

\begin{align*}
\langle A | \psi\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\alpha^*\langle 0 | + \beta^* \langle 1 |)(|01\rangle - |10\rangle)\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\alpha^*\langle 0 | + \beta^* \langle 1 |)(|01\rangle - |10\rangle) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\alpha^*\langle 0 | + \beta^* \langle 1 |)(|0\rangle\otimes|1\rangle - |1\rangle\otimes|0\rangle) 
\end{align*}

I assume I can distribute, so I get terms like $\alpha^*\langle 0 |\big(|0\rangle\otimes|1\rangle\big)$.

But how does one take an inner product between $|0\rangle$ and $|0\rangle\otimes|1\rangle$, when the latter of the two is an element of a tensor product space of different dimension as $|0\rangle$?

Comment: You are right. You cannot take the inner product between $|0\rangle$ and $|0\rangle \otimes |1\rangle$ as, by definition, the inner product is:
$$\langle \rangle : \mathbb{V}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{C}$$
The vector $|0\rangle \otimes |1\rangle$ belongs in the tensor product $\mathbb{V} \otimes \mathbb{V}$, not $\mathbb{V}$.

Comment: @AndreasMastronikolis That's what I thought. In that case, how do we calculate measurement results and measurement probabilities?

Comment: To be honest, I am not currently sure as I am not completely acquainted with product spaces (yet). But here is how I am thinking: You are right in your assertion that the probability of catching $|\psi \rangle$ in the basis state $|A \rangle$ is:
$$| \langle A| \psi \rangle|^2$$
The only thing that is left is to find a vector in $\mathbb{V} \otimes \mathbb{V}$ that will 'represent' (I know I am speaking loosely here) $|A\rangle$. My best guess would be:
$$|A\rangle \otimes | A \rangle$$
but I am not sure.

Comment: Bare in mind, that the quantity
$$\left\lvert \left( \langle A| \otimes \langle A| \right) | \psi \rangle \right\rvert^2$$
is the probability of catching particle 1 in $|A\rangle$ and particle 2 in $|A\rangle$.